# Error origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy Angular

Tags: angular, ionic, http

estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una api a la que no tengo acceso para modificar nada pero me esta devolviendo todo el rato el mismo error :
***from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

He probado a añadir los headers como indicaban en otros post y no funciona, me sigue devolviendo el mismo error, ¿alguna idea de como solucionarlo? a continuación os dejo el código

```
Las cabeceras he probado asi: 
    headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
y asi: headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method").set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE").set("Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

buscarPerfil(api: string, x: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}${api}${x}?api_key=${this.key}`, { headers: this.headers });
}
```

Comment: El import que uso import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: eso se hace en el server

Comment: no hay acceso al server porque es una api

Comment: El problema está del lado del backend, no tiene las políticas definidas para ser consumidas por cualquier persona, si conoces al desarrollador le podrías pedir que las habilite, en caso contrario no hay nada que puedas hacer hasta que den permiso